# Compare number of rows in two tables

Tags: t-sql, join

I have two tables, which share a column, that is not unique. I want all records where table A has more values of the shared column than TABLE B.

```
TABLE A:
Shared_Column|User_ID|Department
123          |    joe|     sales
123          |    joe|     sales
123          |    joe|     sales
124          |    sam|       ops
124          |    sam|       ops

TABLE B
Shared_Column|Other_Column
123          |           1
123          |           1
124          |           4
124          |           4
```

From this data, I want `joe|sales` but not `sam|ops`.  I could also work with this as output:

```
USER|TABLE_A_COUNT|TABLE_B_COUNT
 joe|            3|            2
 sam|            2|            2
```

edit: I've tried to do a join like this:

```
select a.user_ID, count(a.shared_column) as 'TABLE_A_COUNT', count(b.shared_column) as 'TABLE_B_COUNT'
from a inner join b on a.shared_column = b.shared_column
group by a.user_ID
```

but that seems to produce a cross join and I get `joe|6|6` instead of 3 and 2

Thanks!

Comment: how is `tablea_count` = 3 for `joe`? I don't see how you are calculating that.

Comment: hopefully this is clear enough. Both of the real tables are huge so I'm trying to cut the information down to the essentials

Comment: Are same `A.Shared_Column` values always accompanied by same `A.User_ID` values?

Comment: no the user_id doesn't exist in B. b has other data

Comment: All right, however I wasn't not talking about `B`.

Comment: oh sorry. yes they will always have same user_id for the same shared_column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want something like this:

```
select a.user_id,
  count(a.shared_column) TableA,
  TableB
from tablea a
inner join
(
  select count(*) TableB, Shared_column
  from tableb
  group by shared_column
) b
  on a.Shared_Column = b.Shared_Column
group by a.user_id, TableB
```

See [Sql Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ffd8/1)

Result:

```
| USER_ID | TABLEA | TABLEB |
-----------------------------
|     joe |      3 |      2 |
|     sam |      2 |      2 |
```